# Client Side Performance - Laptop and Desktop Specific

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to front end development. Let's say hypothetically my clients have modern hardware, 2.20 GHz CPU, 4GB ram. A flashy website that uses a lot of event handlers, and animations like "slide for div containers to move in and out on users click" and "jquery "on" click for mustache templates created on the fly with ajax (for elements being added after initial DOM load).

I know it depends if my programming skills are really terrible which could be causing the user end to perform really poorly, but lets say I program as close to efficient as possible, and use very well written plug-ins.

**Question** - Do clients with that hardware handle a highly customized design well? Are browser development tools the best out there in terms of troubleshooting and analyzing performance, or is there a highly popular widely used tool that does the job for a lot of developers?

**My question focuses on two key points.**

1. Client Side Performance based on sleek and flashy websites using
   plugins mentioned below on modern hardware.
2. What do developers use to help them check hardware utilization,
   profile and troubleshoot issues.

   - browser development tools is sufficient?
   - A popular tool widley used by developers that I haven't discovered?

---

**Additional Notes**

I am also using my application server to host these files since I am using MVC so its not completely static html files.
 **Plugins include:**

1. **Jquery**
2. **BootstrapJS**
3. **Bootstrap Max Length**
4. **Jquery UI(Effects Corewith Slidejs, its 14Kb in size)**
5. **Jquery Uniform**
6. **MustacheJS**

Jquery Uniform took the biggest hit on page load times I called it on about 100 elements when the page loaded. So I changed it by calling it on elements that needed it when the client clicks on a div to slide open on specific selectors.

**What influenced my question?**
Toying around and reading about Angularjs. Since everything is client side, I read mixed feelings on it slowing the client down and possibly speeding it up. Since I am already knee deep in Jquery I was curious how well it performs with the more modern hardware using a lot of flashy components and DOM manipulation that I mentioned above. This is my first front end design, so I know more seasoned Front End Developers know how well browsers handle these knew frameworks being used.

**Why it's important** 
The temptation to add all the glitter and flashiness to a webpage to make it look more attractive to the client, could actually work against me is a concern.

Comment: It was probably down voted because it is far too broad and is therefore not a very good fit for SO. Please read the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for how to ask a proper question.

Comment: I re-edited and tried to be as specific as possible, I spent more time on my post and realized the less specific I am and the less time I took on a question; I am wasting SO community time. I am new guy, no excuse but I am trying to get better.

Comment: Whatever the processor/memory does not really matter at the client end as you have no control over what is running/memory usage. Could have a high performance lap top with nowt running or it doing a lot. As a web site/server you have not got a clue

Comment: Aaaa thanks for that, that's one variable that hasn't even crossed my mind. I will read about that. But my question was directed toward what we do have control over outside of those variables. Like for example using an excessive amount of event handlers under normal conditions with a ok hardware laptop would be a scenario. When I think about your scenario, combined with a ui thats causing issues, the performance issues would be compounded. I would rather have the clients machine messing it up rather than me lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience you can have hundred of thousands of DOM elements, thousands of objects with arrays inside and nothing happens. In the web are many awful sites made up like Frankenstein's monsters with literally dozens of libraries and have not performance problems in computers from 15 years ago.

While you don't mess with 3d rendering and that experimental things you won't have problems in mainstream PCs. I don't know what your flashy cool features are. Also if you are very bad programming and make almost never-ending loops or something like that could be a problem, but that's anywhere.

Another problem is the download time, and is the most important thing to care about, if you have tons of code it will take longer to download. Usually in server applications you prefer performance before lightness but in the front end is better to download small files. Internet always will be slower than the CPU and RAM.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time out to respond, I'm getting better at Jquery but I was getting a little trigger happy with events and not knowing what the heck is going on in the back end. So I started to become more aware, that I should be paying attention to it. Thanks.